# How can I create a ForeignKey leaving chances for different models for the TO field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-relations

I have multiple product models like below

```
class ProductBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProductOne(ProductBase):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 

class ProductTwo(ProductBase):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ProductThree(ProductBase):
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Each of these products is expected to have an image_set, so I created the model below for product's images

```
class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=[HERE IS THE PROBLEM], on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload-path')
```

How can I get the product field in my Image class to point to any of the products defined above as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductOne, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload-path')
```

there is no 'to' attribute you just refer it to the model that you want

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have just one model for all the products, for example:

```
class Product(ProductBase):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)   #here for example you put the individual info from the different types of products
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True) #add null=True so you don't have to add it for all the products
    etc...
```

Then you don't need a separate `Image` model, you can just add it as a field to your `Product` model. I believe this is a cleaner way to implement it, as there is no real need to have multiple models in this case.